# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. What shoul I do?

Tags: sql-server

```
create table employee_tbl
(
EmpID int primary key,
FirstName varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50),
Salary float,
MobileNo varchar(15)
)

create table employeeaudit_tbl
(
EmpID int primary key,
AuditData varchar(50)
)

select * from employee_tbl
select * from employeeaudit_tbl

create trigger tr_employee_tbl_forinsert
on employee_tbl
for insert
as
begin
        declare @EmpID int
        select @EmpID = EmpID from inserted

        insert into employeeaudit_tbl
        values('New employee with EmpID = ' + CAST(@EmpID as nvarchar(5)) +'is added at ' + CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(50)))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error message:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

Your trigger code:

```
create trigger tr_employee_tbl_forinsert
on employee_tbl
for insert
as
begin
        declare @EmpID int
        select @EmpID = EmpID from inserted

        insert into employeeaudit_tbl
        values('New employee with EmpID = ' + CAST(@EmpID as nvarchar(5)) +'is added at ' + CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(50)))
end
```

If you read the error message clearly it is telling you that one of the things that you are attempting to do has an incorrect number of arguments when compared to the table definition.

Looking at your table definition and `insert`, we see:

- Table: 2 columns
- Insert statement: 1 value provided

Therefore your `INSERT` statement needs changing. You haven't provided the EmpID.

```
insert into employeeaudit_tbl
        values(@EmpID, 'New employee with EmpID = ' + CAST(@EmpID as nvarchar(5)) +'is added at ' + CAST(GETDATE() as nvarchar(50)))
```

Comment: Agree with the diagnosis entirely, but `EmpID` would be wrong to use in `values` like that, because it doesn't look like either a variable name or a function name, and other kinds of names would be invalid in that context. Replacing it with `@EmpID` would seem to me incorrect too, because the audit table is likely supposed to have its own set of IDs independent of the employee table. I mean, the OP is clearly confused but the proposed solution example might confuse them more. As we don't know how the ID is supposed to be generated, maybe it should be some kind of a placeholder there.

Comment: An alternative solution might be to suggest that the audit table's ID column be redefined as an identity column.

Comment: @AndriyM I thought the whole audit thing was initially wrong too, but it's only auditing ON INSERT, so there will be a 1-to-1 relationship between the two tables

Comment: That's a good point, didn't realise that.

Comment: The logic here is still going to fail to properly audit a multi-row insert (e.g. `insert dbo.employee_tbl(empID, etc.) VALUES(1, etc.),(2, etc.);`).